# how to represent state object as typescript interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I thought I am comfortable with Javascript and React, but currently suffering through typescript learning curve. I have my react state defined as:

```
state = {
    fields: { // list of fields
        symbol: '',
        qty: '',
        side: ''
    },
    fieldErrors: {}
};
```

I want to be able to use it as following (dictionary):

```
   onInputChange = (name :string, value :string, error :string) => {
        const fields = this.state.fields;
        const fieldErrors = this.state.fieldErrors;
        fields[name] = value;
        fieldErrors[name] = error;
        this.setState({fields, fieldErrors});
    }
```

How do I represent my state in terms of Typescript?  I am trying something like:

```
interface IFields {
    name: string
}

interface IOrderEntryState {
    fields: IFields,
    fieldErrors: IFields
}
```

Pardon if my question sounds illiterate, totally new at this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your snippet, it looks like `fields[name]` is assigning an arbitrary key to that object. So you probably want to use an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) to represent that instead of the hardcoded key `name` as you have now.

So your interfaces probably should look more like this:

```
interface IFields {
    // This is an index signature. It means this object can hold
    // a key of any name, and they can be accessed and set using
    // bracket notation: `this.state.fields["somekey"]`
    [name: string]: string
}

interface IOrderEntryState {
    fields: IFields,
    fieldErrors: IFields
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dictionary you can declare one using [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) with [index property](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html). It would look like this:

```
interface Dictionary<TKey, TVal> {
    [key: TKey]: TVal;
}

interface IOrderEntryState {
    fields: Dictionary<string, string>,
    fieldErrors: Dictionary<string, string>
}
```

This makes `IOrderEntryState.fields` have arbitrary string attribute names with string values.